# How To Customise A Header

Tags: html, css, blogger

The issue I'm facing today is with the width of a gadget. I would like the `border-bottom` line of `#customheader` to extend to the full width of any given screen. Right now however the `border-bottom` is only the width of the blog. How would I go about lengthening the `border-bottom` without compromising on the other elements of the gadget?

The URL to my blog is as follows: http://www.blankesque.com and the coding to the gadget is stated below:

```
 <style>
     #customheader a {
         font-size: 60px;
         font-family: lato light, 'cantarell';
         color: #737373;
         text-transform: uppercase;
         font-weight: normal!important;
         letter-spacing: 0.07em;
     }
     #customheader {
         margin: 7% 0 2% 0;
         padding: 0 0 3.5% 0;
         border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
     }
     #customheader a:hover {
         color: #000000!important;
     }
 </style>

 <center>
     <div id='customheader'>
         <a href='http://www.blankesque.com'>Blankesque</a>
     </div>
 </center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to move it outside of `.content-outer`, which is set to 1080px.

If possible, move the entire `<header>...</header>` outside of `.content-outer`

[image: You can see the arrangement of the HTML elements here and how it affected the page styling]

Answer (score 0):

you could add an invisible div with `position: absolute` where you need the border, and set the width to 100%. Then you can either set the border on that or use the div as a border.

[example JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L62vncoj/)

Answer (score -1):

If you want a line that goes below your `#customerheader` and extends to the full width of the screen then its best to introduce an independent `<hr/>` which sits below your `<center>` element and has the following CSS properties:

```
hr {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
```

Keep in mind, you will have to remove the `border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;` from your `#customerheader`, since the horizontal line element is replacing this effect.

In retrospect, the above is not even necessary if you fix the layout issues in your site, which are causing your elements to seem to be *out of alignment*. You need to look into what is making them skew to the left, but with the code you have provided I cannot easily identify the root of the issue.

Let me know if you have any questions